# Raspbian NextCoud "Access through untrusted domain" because of HTTPS

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, ssl, https, nextcloud

I've got a nextcloud installation on Rasbpian which was working well over HTTP (port 80). I could access it with both WAN IP and domain name (tunneled through openVPN on a VPS as I don't have a static IP for my nextcloud server and am sitting behind a CGNAT).

I enabled HTTPS with `nextcloud.enable-https lets-encrypt` and followed the steps. Along the way I got

`object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.`

which didn't seem to be a problem as the final result was

`done`

However, now, when I...

...browse to nextcloud using https from another machine via WAN IP address I get the usual certificae warning as the certificate is issued to the domain name,not the ip. ==> So that's OK.

...browse to nextcloud using https from another machine via domain name, I get an `Access through untrusted domain` error. ==> Not OK

...browse to nextcloud using https from another machine via LAN IP, I also get that error. ==> Not OK

...browse to nextcloud using https from the nextcloud server via https://localhost, I only get the certificate warning but can ignore it and then get access to nextcloud. ==> OK.

I tried adding `https://` and/or `:443` to the entries in the trusted domain array in nextcloud's config.php but nothing changes.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot? Thanks.

Comment: The documentation https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/15/admin_manual/installation/installation_wizard.html#trusted-domains lists [fe80::1:50] as a trusted domain, but nothing about ports or HTTPS... I wonder what that example means.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I had two directories in my `/var/snap/nextcloud/` directory: `15763` and `15578`. I changed the wrong `config.php`.

I have no idea though how I got two directories and what that number is all about...